# Blender not working in Windows 10, any suggestions?

Tags: windows

Yesterday, I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and I had Blender version 2.75a installed before the update. Went to load blender and I get that script box that pops up to load blender and then nothing happens. The box does not show anything and then it just closes. Any suggestions?

I have tried reinstalling blender after the update. Same thing happens.

Comment: Reinstall C++ 2012 redist here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679 might help

Comment: I have tried both and still no luck. The Blender-app.exe does the same thing as stated above (opens the script box). I also reinstalled the C++ Redist, no dice. . Thanks for the suggestions. Anything else come to mind?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34901/does-blender-work-in-windows-10

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to wait for blender to come out with a compatibility update. If you're a major blender user, I'd refrain from updating to windows 10.

Comment: update the dirvers for your gpu

Answer (score 4):

I've been using Blender one Windows 10 for a while and have not had any problems.

Some tips:

- Run the latest version
- [Run as Administrator](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/always-run-a-program-in-administrator-mode-in-windows-10/)
- Try the installer instead of the zip, or the zip instead of the installer