# Does Blender work in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, installation

Windows upgraded itself (from 8.1) without uninstalling Blender, but Blender wouldn't correctly work after this (look at the error message below).

Video won't show.

Does Blender work with Windows 10? What's the proper way to install it?

Here's the message:
[image: Blender error message]

It might be a matter of my hardware not being correctly detected by the new Windows, but anyway it's a good question. Does Blender work in Windows 10? Has anybody succeeded installing any version?

Comment: I wonder if the drivers for the graphics card need to be updated too.

Comment: Many 3D programs are likely to show similar problems for you right now.  I'm guessing that you either have an nVidia, ATI, or Intel graphics processor.  You should find out which it is and go to the manufacturers website to locate the appropriate driver for your OS/GPU combination.

Comment: Is there a software gl included in windows version because there is in linux.

Comment: Ok.Blender does work fine in Windows 10. It downloaded automatically the correct drivers, after some time and a few reboots. I guess I should erase this question? Or should I simply answer my own question?

Comment: @Ignorante please do write an answer to the question. I'm sure more people are going to run into the same issue now that W10 is out.

Comment: I had no problem with Blender when I installed Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes. Blender 2.75a works in Windows 10.**

But I had some trouble making it work. After the upgrade from W8.1 to W10 it didn't work, but it was a problem of the new windows not having the correct drivers.

I didn't have to spend much time working it out. Windows 10 did, after some time and a few reboots, offer to install the correct drivers. That fixed most of the problems, including the usual trouble with hardware controls in laptops.

So, if you are upgrading to Windows 10, you might have some problems, but Blender will work well once your computer has Windows properly installed. At least it does with my Hardware.